# Creating a custom View Controller Animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a view controller animation where the view controller the user is currently on slide down and of the screen, revealing the new view controller bellow. So the new view controller would act like a background, with the new one sliding down and revealing it. I have given it a shot but haven't had any success. How would you recommend doing this?

Here is what I have tried:

```
-(void)showLogout:(UIButton *)sender {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"TermsAccepted"];

    WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1200, 320, 568);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeViewController animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)showLogout:(UIButton *)sender {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"TermsAccepted"];

    WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController cache:YES];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1200, 320, 568);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeViewController animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```